# USB can't read configurations, error -71?

Tags: usb, arm, beagleboard

I'm trying to plug a custom development board based on a Beaglebone Black to my Linux PC.

The following is the dmesg error I was able to get (running Ubuntu 12.04):

```
[424595.900132] usb 5-2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using uhci_hcd
[424596.075024] usb 5-2: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/all
[424596.075032] usb 5-2: can't read configurations, error -71
[424596.188220] usb 5-2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using uhci_hcd
[424596.251145] usb 5-2: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/all
[424596.251158] usb 5-2: can't read configurations, error -71
[424596.364184] usb 5-2: new full-speed USB device number 6 using uhci_hcd
[424596.422150] usb 5-2: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/all
[424596.422164] usb 5-2: can't read configurations, error -71
[424596.423023] hub 5-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
```

I've been looking around to see if I can find any information on this error, but I've found very little. Does anyone have any idea what this error means?

Since this is an exercise to get Ethernet over USB0 working, our board has nothing programmed on flash and we are not using an SD card.

Any information will help.
Thanks